Как устранить ошибку Error:java: invalid target release: 17
Получаю ошибку при компиляции проекта Spring Boot 3, версия java 17.  В чем может быть проблема, все уже перепробовал?

Версия java: 
Версия java в IDEA и maven:





POM.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.workproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>XLSX5</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>XLSX5</name>
    <description>XLSX parcer  project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3</version>

    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


Проблема может быть вызвана тем, что в соответствии со скриншотом Project Structure в IDEA выставлен уровень языка Java 9, который и будет применяться для компиляции, независимо от того, что прописано в pom.xml и от реальной версии JDK, установленной в системе.
И скорее всего это и есть причина, что на первом скриншоте отображается сообщение javac8 was used to compile java sources.
Следует изменить это значение:

Также можно попробовать скомпилировать проект непосредственно Maven'ом: mvn clean package (независимо от настроек IDEA).

Проблема была в том, что в текущей версии IDEA не было возможности сменить на 17 верисию language level . Установил новую IDEA и починилось.   Теперь столкнулся с другой проблемой. Работаю через прокси, не пойму в чем дело. Вчера еще все работало. Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.4.2 from/to central (repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.0.215,repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.64.215, repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.128.215] failed: Connect timed out

А откуда взялась версия spring-boot-starter-parent:2.4.2, если в pom.xml указан Spring Boot 3.0?

случайно с другого проекта указал, но суть не меняется , прошу помочь пожалуйста

Помочь с чем?  Если у вас внезапно пропал доступ к maven repository, скорее всего отвалился прокси-сервер.
